# Como saber la cantidad de RAM (pila) que consume una función recursiva en javascript

Tags: javascript, recursión, stack, ram

Tengo una función recursiva simple para calcular el número **`n`** de Fibonacci, si por ejemplo, llamo la función para encontrar el número 40 esta es llamada  **331160281** veces, y supongo que consumirá un alto volumen de RAM(al menos pila).

Al momento de ingresar al inspector de memoria no veo un consumo destacable de RAM en los navegadores.

Mi Pregunta es:

¿cómo hago para saber la cantidad de memoria RAM (pila) que consume un script de `javascript`?.

Si me equivoco y no consume mucha RAM, entonces:

¿como puedo ver la pila consumida en tiempo?

**Código de ejemplo:**

```js
function fibonacci(num){
  count++;
  if (num < 2) return num;
  else return(fibonacci(num - 1) + fibonacci(num - 2));
}

var count=0;
document.write("El 40 número de Fibonacci es: "+fibonacci(40)+"<br>");
document.write("La funcion de Fibonacci se ha llamado "+count+" veces.<br>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me auto respondo.
El problema es que realmente no llega a consumir tanta pila, el recorrido de llamadas tiene forma de árbol, y cuando termina una rama, antes de continuar la siguiente ya ha "retornado" la función, así que vacía la pila.
De manera que buscando el numero 40, solo guarda a pila como máximo 41 llamadas (de f(40) a f(0) ), que consumiría  328 Bytes en un sistema de 64bits.

Comment: como obtuviste esto: `consumiría 320 Bytes en un sistema de 64bits.`

Comment: En un sistema de 64 bits, entiendo que cada puntero ocupa 8 Bytes, de manera que si la "rama" mas alta del recorrido son 41 llamadas consecutivas, 41*8 son 328 Bytes que consumirán los 41 punteros mandados a la pila.
(Ah, ya vi que me equivoque y puse 320, edito)

Answer (score 0):

Solo se me ocurre que mires la RAM que utiliza esa pestaña en tu navegador, por ejemplo *Google Chrome* tiene un administrador de tareas muy parecido al de Windows y creo que te servirá de mucho ya que muestra la memoria y CPU utilizada por las extensiones o pestañas del navegador.

Para acceder a este puede ser por la combinación de teclas **Shift + Escape** o en defecto desde el **botón de menú** acceder a la opción **Más herramientas** y posteriormente seleccionar **Administrador de tareas**.

Aunque en si no te dice cuanto consumirá tu Script pero es una buena herramienta para saber cuanto consume tu sitio es muy importante manejar eso debido a los moviles.
[image: Administrador de Tareas Chrome]